# Guardar archivo y visualizar en la galería

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Actualmente, estoy haciendo una app que me permite mostrar imágenes mediante un `Spinner` en `AndroidStudio`. La cuestión es que, mediante un `LongClick` le permito al usuario guardar esa imagen. Hasta aquí, funciona todo correcto pero me gustaría saber: ¿Cómo hago para visualizar esos archivos en la galería de fotos de los móviles? Ya que, aunque el archivo exista en la carpeta por algún motivo no los veo en la galería.

Mi método para almacenar las imágenes:

```
private void GuardarImagen(Bitmap finalBitmap, String nombre) {
    File directorio = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "Genshin Impact Recursos BUILDS");
    if(!directorio.exists()){
        directorio.mkdirs();
    }
    String fname = nombre;
    File file = new File (directorio, fname+ ".jpg");
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "¡Guardado con éxito!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "¡Ha ocurrido un error al momendo de guardar la imagen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

El cómo lo ejecuto:

```
                imgPJ.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        if(permissionHelper.hasPermission()){
                            //convertir imagen a bitmap
                            imgPJ.buildDrawingCache();
                            Bitmap bmap = imgPJ.getDrawingCache();
                            GuardarImagen(bmap, personajes.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        }else{
                            ejecutar();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

**El método ejecutar solo es para corroborar que se acepten los permisos

Carpeta donde se guardan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Visualización de la galería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**UPDATE:**
He conseguido visualizar las imágenes mediante la siguiente forma, primero creo el método:

```
private void escanearArchivo(String path) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(Builds.this, new String[]{path}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.d("Tag", "Escaneo finalizado. Ya puedes ver las imágenes en la galería.");
        }
    });
}
```

Luego, añado el método en guardado de la misma:

```
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "¡Guardado con éxito!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        escanearArchivo(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Pero, esto no ha funcionado correctamente, ya que aunque guarde la imagen a veces esta no se ve en la galería. ¿Algunas otra sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He conseguido visualizar las imágenes mediante la siguiente forma, primero creo el método:

```
private void escanearArchivo(String path) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(Builds.this, new String[]{path}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.d("Tag", "Escaneo finalizado. Ya puedes ver las imágenes en la galería.");
        }
    });
}
```

Luego, añado el método en guardado de la misma:

```
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "¡Guardado con éxito!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        escanearArchivo(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Comment: Solucionaste tu problema con algo mas?

Comment: Pues en su momento, me sirvió, ahora no se jaja, ¿Tienes problemas para hacerlo? @BrunoSosaFastTag

Answer (score 1):

En Kotlin, lo hago con esa función

```kotlin
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun saveImageToPNG(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap, name: String = "share.png", folder: String? = null) {
    val fos: OutputStream
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val resolver = context.contentResolver
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/$folder")
        val imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
        fos = resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri!!)!!
    } else {
        val imagesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
        ).toString() + File.separator + folder

        val file = File(imagesDir);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }

        val image = File(imagesDir, "$name.png")
        fos = FileOutputStream(image)

    }

    val saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
    fos.flush()
    fos.close()
}
```

Su uso, es simple

```kotlin
saveImageToPNG(requireContext(),  bitmap)
```

la guarda en la galeria con el nombre por defecto `share.png`, se puede especificar un nombre y carpeta.

En mi dispositivo tras ejecutar esa función se actualiza la galeria y me aparece las imágenes.